# Java filename with bracket

Tags: java, file, parentheses

I'm always getting an error when I try to read some files from my flashdrive. All of the files contain a left parenthesis but not a right one. I have too many files to change each file seperately.

Thats my code:

```
String src;
src = "C:\\Users\\Marc\\Desktop\\Musik\\02 The Uncrushables (feat. ILL Bill.mp3"
File tempMP3 = new File(src);
```

And that the Error message I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.farng.mp3.TagException: Unable to create FilenameTag
at org.farng.mp3.MP3File.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.farng.mp3.MP3File.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.farng.mp3.MP3File.<init>(Unknown Source)
at NewID3.main(NewID3.java:55)
Caused by: org.farng.mp3.TagException: Unmatched parenthesis in "02 The Uncrushables (feat. ILL Bill" at position : 20
    at org.farng.mp3.filename.FilenameTagBuilder.parseParenthesis(Unknown Source)
    at org.farng.mp3.filename.FilenameTagBuilder.createCompositeFromToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.farng.mp3.filename.FilenameTagBuilder.createFilenameTagFromMP3File(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
Java Result: 1
```

Does anybody know how I can solve this?

Thanks for ur help in advance!

PS: If i haven't explained myself clearly enough please tell me and I'll try to do better.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Java *per se*. It's the library you're using.

```
Caused by: org.farng.mp3.TagException: Unmatched parenthesis in "02 The Uncrushables (feat. ILL Bill" at position : 20
    at org.farng.mp3.filename.FilenameTagBuilder.parseParenthesis(Unknown Source)
```

Your library is attempting to parse the filename. A simple Java `File` object wouldn't care at all.

Comment: MP3File mp3 = new MP3File(src);
I tried that, but im still getting the same error, or what are u refering to?